# Is it a bug of the implementation of std::valarray in gcc?

Tags: c++, gcc, operator-overloading, c++20, valarray

I tried the following program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <valarray>

int main( void ) 
{
    std::valarray<int> v1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    std::valarray<int> v2 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    auto v3 = v1 * v2;

    for ( const auto &item : v3 ) std::cout << item << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

and got an error message that an appropriate function `begin` for `v3` used implicitly in this statement

```
    for ( const auto &item : v3 ) std::cout << item << ' ';
```

can not be found.

So I tried the following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <valarray>
#include <type_traits>

int main( void ) 
{
    std::valarray<int> v1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    std::valarray<int> v2 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    auto v3 = v1 * v2;

    std::cout << std::is_same<std::valarray<int>, decltype( v3 )>::value << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

and got the result

```
0
```

But when this statement

```
auto v3 = v1 * v2;
```

is changed to

```
std::valarray<int> v3 = v1 * v2;
```

then the output is

```
1
```

The `operator *` for `std::valarray<int>` is declared the following way

```
template<class T> valarray<T> operator* (const valarray<T>&, const valarray<T>&);
```

So is it a bug of the implementation of `std::valarray<int>`?

Comment: If you replace `auto v3 = ...` with `std::valarray<int> v3 = ...` the code compiles and runs as expected. By using `auto`, `v3` is some intermediate expression template generated type.

Comment: Operators on `valarray` are allowed to return proxy objects, which lets the implementation optimize multiple operations like `a * b + c` into a single loop. I don't know if the proxy objects need to implement `begin()` and `end()` or not.

Comment: See http://eel.is/c++draft/valarray.syn#3.sentence-1, which implies that you're not allowed to use `auto` and have the expectations on it that you're testing for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's wrong with std::valarray's operator\*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56222576/whats-wrong-with-stdvalarrays-operator)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a bug.  `std::valarray::operator*` does not actually have to return a `std::valarray` because it is allowed to use expression templates.  That means  it can return a type that has the following properties:

> - All const member functions of `std::valarray` are provided.
> - `std::valarray`, `std::slice_array`, `std::gslice_array`, `std::mask_array` and `std::indirect_array` can be constructed from the replacement type.
> - **All functions accepting an argument of type `const std::valarray&` except `begin()` and `end()` (since C++11) should also accept the replacement type**.
> - All functions accepting two arguments of type `const std::valarray&` should accept every combination of `const std::valarray&` and the replacement type.
> - The return type does not add more than two levels of template nesting over the most deeply-nested argument type.

<sup>emphasis mine [source](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray/operator_arith3)</sup>

Because of this, you need to explicitly capture the return as a `std::valarray` so the specialization for `std::begin` can be called.